# Performance aggregrate MongoDB match and sample

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, nosql, aggregate, database-performance

I have a collection with 7 million records. I need to pick X random elements between a specific date range.

This is my schema

```
mongoose.Schema({
        transactionId: {type: String, required: [true, 'transactionId is required'], index: true},
        createdAt: {type: Date, required: [true, 'date is required'], index: true},
        userId: {type: String, required: [true, 'userId is required']}
    });
```

This is the query I am doing

```
TransactionModel.aggregate([
        {
            $match: {
                createdAt: {$gte: startDate, $lt: endDate}
            }
        },
        {
            $sample: {
                size: 100,
            }
        }
    ]
```

And these are my results:

```
Took 458ms to select 100 winners in date range: 1-5-2018 - 1-6-2018
Took 1524ms to select 100 winners in date range: 1-5-2018 - 1-9-2018
Took 2052ms to select 100 winners in date range: 1-4-2018 - 1-4-2019
Took 19249ms to select 100 winners in date range: 1-1-2018 - 1-1-2033
```

The 19 seconds seems relatively long, when I remove the $match from the aggregate function it takes only 142ms to pick 100 winners from 7 million records.

Is there a way I can improve speed with the match clause?

Comment: have you created indexing on `createdAt` field?

Answer (score 0):

As Anthony Winzlet already wrote, you need an index on the createdAt field. This can either be a single field index or a compound index where createdAt is the first part.

In addition to that, you should consider to have a $project stage in case not all fields of the document are needed.

Ideally you have compound index, which is covering your query.

You can use explain() to see what's going on:

```
collection.find(
  {createdAt: {$gte: startDate, $lt: endDate}}, 
  { created: 1, otherField: 1 }
).explain('executionStats')
```